# suggestions on creating a admin page using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am pretty new in developing web applications using Java. I have developed a small application which is a login & registration page both of which are working fine. Now, I have decided on making a admin page(using jsp). In my java code I control the redirection of jsp pages (if user!="admin"then home.jsp else user=="admin" then admin.jsp). in my admin page what I want to do is I want the admin to be able to view all the users registered and can edit their details or delete them. Someone can please suggest me on how to achieve this.

Login Servlet.java(code where I decide between admin & regular user)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String errorMsg = null;
        String name;
        if(email == null || email.equals("")){
            errorMsg ="User Email can't be null or empty";
        }
        if(password == null || password.equals("")){
            errorMsg = "Password can't be null or empty";
        }

        if(errorMsg != null){
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
            PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>"+errorMsg+"</font>");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }else{

        Connection con = (Connection) getServletContext().getAttribute("DBConnection");
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select id, name, email,country from Users where email=? and password=?");
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs != null && rs.next()){

                User user = new User(rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("country"), rs.getInt("id"));
               name=rs.getString("name");
               System.out.println("Name:"+ name);
                //if(rs.getString("name")!="admin")
               if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
                {
                logger.info("User found with details="+user);
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("User", user);
                response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
                }
                // String rs1=rs.getString();
                else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
                {
                logger.info("Admin found with details="+user);
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("User", user);
                response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
                }

            }else{
                RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                logger.error("User not found with email="+email);
                out.println("<font color=red>No user found with given email id, please register first.</font>");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Database connection problem");
            throw new ServletException("DB Connection problem.");
        }finally{
            try {
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("SQLException in closing PreparedStatement or ResultSet");;
            }

        }
        }
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="com.javadbproject.util.User"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Home Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/loginstyle.css'/>"> 

</head>
<body>
<%User user = (User) session.getAttribute("User"); %>
<h3>Hi <%=user.getName() %></h3>
<strong>Your Email</strong>: <%=user.getEmail() %><br>
<strong>Your Country</strong>: <%=user.getCountry() %><br>
<br>
<form action="Logout" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Logout" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

AuthenticationServlet

```
package com.javadbproject.servlet.filters;


import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@WebFilter("/AuthenticationFilter")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        logger.info("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        logger.info("Requested Resource::"+uri);

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        if(session == null && !(uri.endsWith("html") || uri.endsWith("Login") || uri.endsWith("Register"))){
            logger.error("Unauthorized access request");
            res.sendRedirect("login.html");
        }else{
            // pass the request along the filter chain
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }


    }

    public void destroy() {
        //close any resources here
    }

}
```

I am looking to develop my admin.jsp on the similar lines as my home.jsp

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

1. You need a database [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) would be nice to start with.
2. You need to have a [mysql connector jar file](https://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&).
3. Create a `class User` for example.

   ```
   public class User{
      String iduser;
      String name;
      String username;
      String password;

      //setters and getters
   }
   ```
4. Create a table for user in mysql or any database that you have.

   CREATE  TABLE `sampleapplication`.`user` (
     `iduser` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
     `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
     `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
     `usercol` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`) );
5. Let's start the `database with java`. :)  add the mysql connector jar file in your build path `(right click project > Build path > Configure build path > Click Add external jar > Locate mysql connector)`, and paste it in your `web-inf>lib` folder.
6. Create a `class for database transaction`. for [reference](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

   ```
   public class DatabaseTransaction{

      public List<User> readDataBase() throws Exception {
        try {
           // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           // setup the connection with the DB.
           connect = DriverManager
             .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?"
                  + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");

           // statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
           statement = connect.createStatement();
           // resultSet gets the result of the SQL query
           resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("select * from user");

           List<User> listOfUsers=new ArrayList<User>();
            User userToAdd;

           while (resultSet.next()) {
               userToAdd = new User();
               userToAdd.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
               userToAdd.setPassword(resultSet.getString("pword"));
               userToAdd.setUserid(resultSet.getString("userid"));
               userToAdd.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
               listOfUsers.add(userToAdd);
           }
       }
     }
   ```
7. call the `DatabaseTransaction` to your `filter/controller/servlet`

   ```
   DatabaseTransaction databaseTransaction = DatabaseTransaction();

   //use your `HttpServletRequest`
   //parameters are key and value
   //store as attribute to access in jsp page
   request.setAttribute("userList",databaseTransaction.readDataBase());

   //then forward the page using `HttpServletRequest` 
   //dont use response.redirect(); you wont be able to use the attribute because you are using a response 
   //filename of the jsp
   request.getRequestDispatcher("adminpage").forward(request, response);
   ```
8. In your jsp page. use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/download.html)

   ```
    //import the core tag library
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

     //lastly loop through the list attribute
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Username</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <c:foreach items="${userList}" var="user">
             <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user.iduser}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.username}"/></td>
             </tr>
           </c:foreach>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   ```

thats all :)

Comment: Thank you, it's a nice example. I am trying to relate it to the code I already have. I am using Oracle DB. I will try with your inputs. Thanks again!!

Comment: so you only need to do is retrieve them and put in a list

Answer (score 0):

`Servlet` `Filter` is what you need, you need a logical roles for each user and allowable URL patterns per role configured and a Filter filtering each request and blocking/allowing based on it

Comment: Can I know how that can be achieved?

Comment: I have no idea of how I can do it through a Servlet Filter as of how to show a admin page with list of registered users and the flexibility for admin to edit,delete these users. Please guide me on this